# Copy Data Into Same Rows

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm not that great with SQL server, but I'm trying to be able to duplicate/copy patient encounter data from one patient to another patient in the same tables. However, this may be way over my head.

All three of the tables below match on encounter_id, but none of them have a PK. I'd like to be able to write a query/stored procedure in which I can specify the encounter_id to copy and to what patient_id(s). The system would need to generate the next encounter_id(s).

Essentially, we will be seeing multiple people at once and therefore need to copy the encounter that is documented over to all the participants and unfortunately our EMR system doesn't have this capability built into it.

This data comes from three tables:

```
**Table: enc_encounter**

encounter_id   patient_id   encounter_date       encounter_time       etc1   etc2   etc3
186            123          2014-03-12 13:17:47  2014-03-12 13:17:47  123    123    123

**Table: enc_form**

encounter_id   page   recorded_by   recorded_on
186            1      100           2014-03-12 13:17:47
186            2      100           2014-03-12 13:17:47  
186            3      100           2014-03-12 13:17:47
186            4      100           2014-03-12 13:17:47

**Table: enc_formdetail**

encounter_id   page   keyname   keyvalue
186            1      date_1    2014-03-12
186            1      field_1   abc1
186            1      field_1   bcd1 
186            1      field_1   asdf 
186            1      field_1   jkl 
186            1      field_1   asdf 
186            1      field_1   bbb1 
186            1      field_1   cccc2
```

Ideally after the query/stored procedure where I specify the encounter_id to copy and to what patient_id to copy it, the tables would look like this:

```
**Table: enc_encounter**

encounter_id   patient_id   encounter_date       encounter_time       etc1   etc2   etc3
186            123          2014-03-12 13:17:47  2014-03-12 13:17:47  123    123    123
187            456          2014-03-12 13:17:47  2014-03-12 13:17:47  123    123    123

**Table: enc_form**

encounter_id   page   recorded_by   recorded_on
186            1      100           2014-03-12 13:17:47
186            2      100           2014-03-12 13:17:47  
186            3      100           2014-03-12 13:17:47
186            4      100           2014-03-12 13:17:47
187            1      100           2014-03-12 13:17:47
187            2      100           2014-03-12 13:17:47  
187            3      100           2014-03-12 13:17:47
187            4      100           2014-03-12 13:17:47

**Table: enc_formdetail**

encounter_id   page   keyname   keyvalue
186            1      date_1    2014-03-12
186            1      field_1   abc1
186            1      field_1   bcd1 
186            1      field_1   asdf 
186            1      field_1   jkl 
186            1      field_1   asdf 
186            1      field_1   bbb1 
186            1      field_1   cccc2
187            1      date_1    2014-03-12
187            1      field_1   abc1
187            1      field_1   bcd1 
187            1      field_1   asdf 
187            1      field_1   jkl 
187            1      field_1   asdf 
187            1      field_1   bbb1 
187            1      field_1   cccc2
```

Any help or direction that can be provided would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is the same issue, yes. However, I don't think I fully explained myself when I posted the previous question. The answers to that question, while very good and helpful did not get it right (my fault, not the posters)

Answer (score 1):

Worked out for your first table:

```
insert   Table1
         (encounter_id, patient_id, encounter_date, ...other columns...)
select   encounter_id
,        456 -- New patient ID
,        encounter_date
,        ...other columns...
from     Table1
where    encounter_id = 186
```